# Numbers deleted unintentional by removing whitespace using .strip() python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, strip

I only wanted to remove whitespace in my data, the whole dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

fileName = 'home/filepath.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(fileName, sheet_name='october2018')
```

[image]

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if x.dtype == "object" else x)
```

[image]

The ID number in each row is a hyperlink, if it helps. Data in the entire column was wiped out leaving only the column name with NaN values, as shown above. In another column AppID, data e.g '123456' were also deleted. **How can I strip whitespace in the whole dataframe** without having to delete anything else?

```
Date             AppID      App Name    IDNumber   Decision
2018-10-01   com.android    myapp1      NaN         Approve
2018-10-01   com.android    myapp2      NaN         Approve
2018-10-01   com.android    myapp3      NaN         Approve
2018-10-01   com.android    myapp4      NaN         Approve
2018-10-01   NaN            iOSapp1     NaN         Approve
```

Comment: What is your original df's dtypes?

Comment: It may be difficult to diagnose this without having a sample df to work with. Unfortunately an image won't be much help in this case. Could you provide a minimal code example to set up a data frame that reproduces your issue?

Comment: @KevinFang Date                           datetime64[ns]
                      App ID                           object
                      App Name                     object
                      IDNumber                      object
                      Decision                         object

Comment: @MadPhysicist There, I edited my post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `x.str.strip()`, try `x.astype(str).str.strip()`

You'd better make sure the dtype of column is string before using pandas string operation on it. `object` dtype can be heterogeneous.

Comment: Bang! For the win! Thank you, it did exactly what I wanted.